# Greedy Python RegEx capturing group to include "and"

Tags: python, regex, parsing, regular-language

I need some help writing regex expressions. I need an expression that can match the following patterns (including words and digits, spaces and commas):

- Line 145
- Line3544354
- Lines 10,12
- Line items 45,10,26
- Lines 10 and 45

Thus far, I wrote one expression which includes the first three patterns and all case variations:

```
r'(?i)(line item[\.*\,*\s*\d+]+]+|line[\.*\,*\s*\d+]+|lines[\.*\,*\s*\d+]+|line items[\.*\,*\s*\d+]+)'
```

I would like to include the last two patterns listed but not sure how. I have wrote this expression for the pattern matching "Lines 10 and 45" by modifying the capturing group as follows:

```
r'(Lines[\.*\,*\w*\s*\d+]+)'
```

However, it does not work as expected. It selects all word characters in the string. I would like to keep my expressions greedy, but not sure how to implement the last two patterns in the list.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: [`(?i)lines?(?:\s+items?)?\s*\d+(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*\d+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/R3ktxn/1). Or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/R3ktxn/2). `[...]` are character classes, not grouping constructs.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Could you please share a brief explanation of the expression? I am trying to understand what the different ? and () mean within the expression.

Comment: Also I have "Line 96.1" at the beginning of a string in my text but this formula is not capturing it and returns NA. Do you know why? Thank you!

Comment: You did not try my second link solution. I posted it with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)lines?(?:\s+items?)?\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R3ktxn/3).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?i)` - ignore case inline [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)
- `lines?` - `line` or `lines` ([`?` quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) makes the preceding pattern optional, matching 1 or 0 occurrences)
- `(?:\s+items?)?` - an optional [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) matching 1 or 0 occurrences of 1+ whitespaces followed with `item` and an optional `s` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:,|and)` - `,` or `and` char sequence
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits

Comment: Wonderful, you truly are a RegEx expert! Thank you again. I will study your explanation and use it as a reference to review all my RegEx formulas.

Comment: @brightcitrus I do not know how messy your input is, so I suggested the safest pattern. It is a bit long, but is precise. You may further try replacing parts of the regex to see if it still does what you need, say, replace `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` with `\d[.\d]*`, or even replace the whole `\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*` with a `(?:and|[ \d.,])*`.... :)

Comment: Hello Wiktor, I have a quick question please. How can I implement this pattern using an "or" statement? I would like the expression to search for and return all instances of  fmea or doc- such as: 
r'((?i)(fmea|doc\-?)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*)'

But the expression becomes lazy. Any tip please? Thanks.

Comment: @brightcitrus Without sample strings/expected output, it is not clear what problem you have.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I would like to use the same regex you provided but I cannot find the correct modication to match my output.
The string to search includes either "fmea" followed by a number or "doc-" followed by a number. A string might include both fmea followed by number and doc- followed by number. The regex you provided works well but only returns the first occurence of either fmea or doc-. It does not return both when there is both. How can I fix this please?

Comment: @brightcitrus Please use http://regex101.com to share some input strings.

Comment: Thanks! Here is the link https://regex101.com/r/7M4WcZ/1

The regex captures "fmea" and "doc-" but only returns one at the time. How can make it return both when both are present in the string please.

Comment: @brightcitrus Looks like you only included strings with a single repetition, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/7M4WcZ/2) - is it what you are seeking?

Comment: Yes however it does not work in my python environment. This expression is returning "F" only when string is " FMEA 14300".

Comment: I added parentheses around the regex and it runs. Unfortunately, it is still not returning all occurrences within a cell. When "FMEA" is mentioned twice in the same cell, it is only returned once.

Comment: @brightcitrus I have too little idea what you mean. Please provide a reproducible example at https://ideone.com/hw8tYZ. You may fork this demo.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!